When I make a new package inside main package name it's not creating inside the main package. It's made a new folder
When I try to create a new package inside the main package, it's not created inside the main package. Instead, it's made a new folder. This is the image describes my issue
Help me to make directory inside the package name.
Note that my all other projects works fine, only problem on this project.

seems to be IDE configuration, yet you don't even mention what IDE you are using.

it seems like you enabled flatten packages option in project view settings.
